# WPF templating/styling issue

Tags: wpf, styling, templating

Given this piece of XAML

```
<DockPanel>
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <DockPanel>
              <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Border.Resources>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Red" />
                  </Style>
                </Border.Resources>
                <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" />
              </Border>
              <ContentPresenter />
            </DockPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Resources>

  <GroupBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Header="GroupBox header"
      DockPanel.Dock="Top">

    ...
    ...
```

I would like to know why the group box header is not displayed in **red** letters.

I've already tried styling the Label type with no success either.

(sorry about the overly generic post title... I wasn't able to think of something more meaninful)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code solved the problem:

```
<DockPanel>
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
      <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Resources>
              <Style TargetType="Label">
                <Style.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </Style.Setters>
              </Style>
            </DataTemplate.Resources>
            <Label Content="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Resources>

  <GroupBox VerticalAlignment="Top" Header="GroupBox header" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  ...
  ...
```

However, I still don't know why the proposed code didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" >
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Resources>
```

You don't need a templet for this. But if you demand on using a Templete, you probably have to set the Groupbox.HeaderTemplet not the GroupBox.Templet.

**Edit:**

This is what i got so far, but i keep getting an `XamlPraseException`.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" >
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                        </Style>
                    </StackPanel.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding GroupBox.Header}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: That almost works, but it turns into red every TextBlock inside the GroupBox. Besides that, in the code shown in the question I'm simplifying my scenario a bit... actually I'd like to set the "Style" property of the TextBlock conforming the header of the GroupBox.

Comment: Sry, i couldn't help you, but i'm getting an odd error on my Solution(which is similar to Yacoders answer(except it isn't compiling), but i guess i can stop working on that. One solution should be enough).

Comment: I use a tool named Kaxaml to debug such XAML snippets. It's small and handy to play with some style/templates issues...

Comment: The problem is that the HeaderTemplate doesn't accept an ControlTemplate, but if i change to DataTemplate the Templeatebinding don't work. ... I don't care ... I don't need that code working ;)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `ContentPresenter` doesn't use TextBlock to show the string you provide as header or explicitly sets its style, so the style you defined cannot be applied.

If you are certain that you will only use text as group box header, you can remove the `ContentPresenter` and use a `TextBlock` on your own.

```
  <DockPanel>
  <DockPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <DockPanel>
              <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Border.Resources>
                  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                  </Style>
                </Border.Resources>
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"></TextBlock>
              </Border>
              <ContentPresenter />
            </DockPanel>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DockPanel.Resources>

  <GroupBox VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Header="GroupBox header"
      DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
  </DockPanel>
```

Comment: What is that "<ContentPresenter />" for?

Comment: Oh, this question deserves a large separate answer :) But, basically a ContentPresenter will allow you to have almost any type of content in the header: text, images, graphical shapes, etc. While this current solution will only handle a text header.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a2988ae8-e7b8-4a62-a34f-b851aaf13886#contentpresenter

Comment: I know what the ContentPreseneter is for, but i don't see the need for that in your Answer.

Comment: I see, you mean the default content presenter. You still need it if you want to show the group box content.